# travis-ci: incorrect mime type with PHP 5

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm developing a CakePHP plugin that generates thumbnails.
So I wrote some tests that, among other things, verify that the thumbnail mime is correct.

The problem occurs with `bmp` and `psd` files and php 5.5 and 5.6.
In these cases, it seems `mime_content_type()` returns the `application/octet-stream` mime type (instead `image/x-ms-bmp` and `image/vnd.adobe.photoshop`)

The same problem does not occur with the same tests, the same files and php 7.0 or 7.1.

You can see the logs [here](https://travis-ci.org/mirko-pagliai/cakephp-thumber/builds/169506309).

Why does this happen? Is it normal?
How can I fix it?

Comment: no idea what mime_content_type uses for its mime-type library, but if you get different behavior between php5 and php7, it stands to reason that it's NOT using a standard external system library, eg. ./etc/mime.magic or whatever.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB I agree with your supposition, probably it is correct

Answer (score 0):

I've **temporarily** fixed with something like:

```
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6', '>')) {
        $this->assertMime($thumb, 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop');
    } else {
        $this->assertMime($thumb, 'application/octet-stream');
    }
```

Even if a solution like this I do not like even a little.